# Display vulgar fractions with a colon for aspect ratios

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format

How can I *display* floating point numbers in cells as aspect ratios with a colon `:` or ratio symbol `∶` U+2236 instead of a slash `/` in spreadsheet applications?

One can format numeric cell contents to display as a vulgar fraction with a slash between numerator and denominator. My copy of MS Excel has these predefined by default:

- `# ?/?` *single-digt*
- `# ??/??` *double-digit*
- `# ???/???` *triple-digit*
- `# ?/2` *halves*
- `# ?/4` *fourths* or *quarters*
- `# ?/8` *eights*
- `# ?/16` *sixteenths*
- `# ?/10` *tenths*
- `# ?/100` *hundredths*

They all include an optional initial integer `#`. This can be suppressed, of course, e.g. by using `?/?`,  to force values above 1 to have a numerator larger than the denominator.

One can also introduce different fixed denominators, e.g. `?/9` (as is popular in image, video and screen aspect ratios). This does not support floats for numerators as in “19.5∶9” (or even “19½∶9”), because Excel does not allow formatting codes like `?,0/?` to be used.

However, I cannot find a way to alter the character used for the fraction slash `/`.

Comment: afaik there is no way to format the cell in that way, you would have to use a formula to reformat it, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472989/how-do-i-display-a-ratio-in-excel-in-the-format-ab/6570611

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to have a cell containing a number, displayed as you mean to do.
You would have to settle for having text in that cell, referring to another cell holding the corresponding number.

The formula linking the two cells is

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(D1,"?/????"),"/",":"))
```

where `D1` holds the numeric value. This supports fractions with the denominator *up to* four digits, and with no integer part.
It seems you can extend this maximum number of digits, but I guess this is good enough.
The image shows in column F how it works.
The last two rows show how the formula discerns (1+4/999) from (1+4/1001).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a value like ***.125***, pick a cell and enter:

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(0.125,"# ?/8 "),"/",":")
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

The formula can be modified to reference a separate cell like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"# ?/8 "),"/",":")
```

This is for **display purposes** only.  The value given by the formula is *Text* rather than *Numeric*.

Comment: Downvoters, it is best if feedback is posted.